# Cannot scan with Canon TR4550 : SANE_STATUS_DEVICE_BUSY error

Tags: 20.04, scanner, canon

I just purchased a Canon Pixma TR4550. It is connected with USB to my desktop running Ubuntu 20.04.

- For printing, I installed "cnijfilter2-5.70-1-deb" provided by Canon. Printing works fine.
- For scanning, I installed "scangearmp2-3.70-1-deb" also provided by Canon, but I can't make it works, although installation is fine without any error.

Scanner seems correctly detected :

```
$ scanimage -L
device `pixma:04A91854' is a CANON Canon PIXMA TR4500 Series multi-function peripheral
device `escl:http://127.0.0.1:60000' is a ESCL TR4500 series flatbed scanner
```

When I launch simple-scan, it is also detected :

[image: detection OK]

But when I press the scan button , it returns an error (impossible to connect..."), here is the output of "simple-scan -d" command :

```
pascal$ simple-scan -d
[+0,00s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:1720: Starting simple-scan 3.36.3, PID=13292
[+0,00s] DEBUG: unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
[+0,01s] DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
[+0,06s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1906: Loading state from /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+0,06s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1885: Restoring window to 676x421 pixels
[+0,12s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1539: sane_init () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+0,12s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1545: SANE version 1.0.31
[+0,12s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1606: Requesting redetection of scan devices
[+0,12s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:828: Processing request
[+0,51s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+8,29s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:341: sane_get_devices () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+8,29s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:353: Device: name="pixma:04A91854" vendor="CANON" model="Canon PIXMA TR4500 Series" type="multi-function peripheral"
[+8,29s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:353: Device: name="escl:http://127.0.0.1:60000" vendor="ESCL" model="TR4500 series" type="flatbed scanner"
[+8,61s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+11,47s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+14,08s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+15,77s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+15,99s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+16,04s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:1536: Requesting scan at 300 dpi from device 'pixma:04A91854'
[+16,04s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1674: Scanner.scan ("pixma:04A91854", dpi=300, scan_mode=ScanMode.COLOR, depth=8, type=single, paper_width=0, paper_height=0, brightness=0, contrast=0, delay=3000ms)
[+16,04s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:828: Processing request
[+16,37s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+16,56s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:889: sane_open ("pixma:04A91854") -> SANE_STATUS_DEVICE_BUSY
[+16,56s] WARNING: scanner.vala:893: Unable to open device: Device busy
[+16,89s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
```

Any idea what is going wrong here ? why this SANE_STATUS_DEVICE_BUSY ?

Note : I tried launching "scangearmp2" command, but it says "no scanner detected", and research never ends.

Comment: Your screenshot shows an entry for a pixma driver. The dropdown menu should show another driver entry. What does it say and can you scan with it?

Comment: No other driver, dropdown has only this entry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replying to myself as I got it to work : I just connected the printer using Wifi ! (which is recommended by Canon by the way)

I uninstalled the scangearmp2 driver as it seemed to be useless (not detecting scanner, see above), then I disconnect USB cable, and use WPS method to connect the printer to my wifi network (yesterday, I tried entering wifi password with printer keyboard, and it was a mess, thus I used my USB cable...).

Nothing else to do, all is working fine now :

```
pascal$ scanimage -L

device `escl:https://192.168.1.29:443' is a Canon TR4500 series flatbed scanner
[~]
pascal$ 
[~]
pascal$ simple-scan -d
[+0,00s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:1720: Starting simple-scan 3.36.3, PID=26141
[+0,00s] DEBUG: unsetenv() is not thread-safe and should not be used after threads are created
[+0,02s] DEBUG: _g_io_module_get_default: Found default implementation dconf (DConfSettingsBackend) for ‘gsettings-backend’
[+0,07s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1906: Loading state from /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+0,07s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1885: Restoring window to 676x421 pixels
[+0,13s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1539: sane_init () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+0,13s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1545: SANE version 1.0.31
[+0,13s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1606: Requesting redetection of scan devices
[+0,13s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:828: Processing request
[+0,54s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+8,06s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:341: sane_get_devices () -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
[+8,06s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:353: Device: name="escl:https://192.168.1.29:443" vendor="Canon" model="TR4500 series" type="flatbed scanner"
[+8,36s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+12,86s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+14,19s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+14,34s] DEBUG: simple-scan.vala:1536: Requesting scan at 300 dpi from device 'escl:https://192.168.1.29:443'
[+14,34s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:1674: Scanner.scan ("escl:https://192.168.1.29:443", dpi=300, scan_mode=ScanMode.COLOR, depth=8, type=single, paper_width=0, paper_height=0, brightness=0, contrast=0, delay=3000ms)
[+14,34s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:828: Processing request
[+14,66s] DEBUG: app-window.vala:1981: Saving state to /home/pascal/.cache/simple-scan/state
[+14,98s] DEBUG: scanner.vala:889: sane_open ("escl:https://192.168.1.29:443") -> SANE_STATUS_GOOD
```

Good thing to have this resolved !

EDIT : during investigations, I updated libsane-common from [sane-project](https://launchpad.net/%7Esane-project) web site. Not sure this was required, but better to mention :

```
pascal$ sudo apt show libsane-common
[sudo] Mot de passe de pascal : 
Package: libsane-common
Version: 1.0.31+git20210131-focal0
```

EDIT 2 : I has an issue to detect the scanner from a VM (QEMU) in hosted mode. That was resolved editing `/etc/sane.d/escl.conf` file, and adding a new device line like below :

```
device https://192.168.1.29:443 "Canon TR4550 Serie"
```

(as shown with the `scanimage -L` output from the host above).

Comment: Glad you resolved this issue, pled. Regarding scangearmp2: for you, and other users, it should be noted that it is not a SANE backend driver. Clarification is [here](https://wiki.debian.org/Scanner#canon).

Comment: This workaround also works for the Canon TS7400 series.